# android ndk debug trap

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

In NDK (Only-native-C++) applications what is the correct way to set a programmatic debug trap? I mean stopping the application with possiblity to examine call stack, variables, etc.
For instance, under WIN32 debug trap in my GameEngine is declared as

```
#define DIE() __asm{ int 3 }
```

and for iOS it's

```
#   if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#       define DIE() {__asm__("int3");}
#   else
#       define DIE() {__asm__("trap");}
#   endif
```

What would be a correct one for an Android NDK application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

__android_log_assert(...) from "android/log.h" should do the work.

This should break you into debugger since it raises SIGTRAP.
See http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ for a usage summary.

Comment: It calls `abort()`, it's not just a debug trap.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <signal.h>
raise(SIGTRAP);
```

or like in http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/system/core/liblog/logd_write.c function: __android_log_assert

```
__builtin_trap();
```

Comment: Not `__builtin_trap()`, this ones calls `abort()`. The proper function is `__builtin_debugtrap()`.